# XSD element with attribute and maxlength restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

I can't seem to find a solution to a simple problem. I need to write a xsd file.

I want to hava a xml file like this:

```
<info lang="someLang">Some long text not longer than 3000</info>
```

I'm unable to get the maxLength restriction. Right now I tried something like this, but this is not right.

```
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Info">
    <complexType>
        <simpleContent>
            <restriction base="string">
                <maxLength value="3000" />
                <attribute name="lang" type="language"/>            
            </restriction>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not right"?

Comment: - src-ct.2.1: Complex Type Definition Representation Error for type '#AnonType_InfoAdType'. When <simpleContent> is used, the base type must be a complexType whose content type is simple, or, only if restriction is specified, a complex 
  type with mixed content and emptiable particle, or, only if extension is specified, a simple type. 'string' satisfies none of these conditions.
 - Start tag of element <restriction>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty obscure.

A complex type with simple content is always derived by extension from the simple type. So you need to define a simple type as a restriction of xs:string with the maxLength constraint, and then define the complex type by extension from this.